# Altcoin transfers

Tags: metamask

I sent a number of ERC20 tokens to Metamask. They are not showing in the MM wallet, but I do see them in Etherscan. I now want to sent them to a different address but I don't see how to do that. When I try to add those tokens directly in MM, I can't seem to do so. Prior discussion of this seem to indicate that once tokens do into MM, they cannot be sent out. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To see your token balance in metamask, you has to add your ERC20 token address in metamask.
->Click menu in top left corner of metamask popup 
->Click 'Add Token'
->Select custom token and paste your token address in given field
->Then click next and after that click 'Add tokens'
Now token balance for your address will be displayed on metamask and you can transfer tokens to other address

Comment: Thank you! I did it. Much appreciated!